# using class and csv file to convert

Tags: csv

```
import csv

class Converter:       
    def __init__(self,csv):
        with open(csv) as f:
            obj = csv.reader(f)
            conversions = list(obj)
            conversions.pop(0)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    with open("table.csv", "w") as f:
        f.write("type,ratio\ncm_to_inch,0.393701\ninch_to_cm,2.54")

    cvt = Converter("table.csv")

    r1 = cvt.convert(5.5, "cm", "inch") 
    r2 = cvt.convert(100, "inch", "cm") 

    print(f"{r1}\n{r2}")
```

So I am trying to use class to convert each values from cm to inches and inches to cm. These conversion rate will be written in csv file. However, when I activate this code, AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'reader' continuously pop up. Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's probably a resolution issue try changing the name of your constructor parameter to something other than csv like csv_name, because that's what is being referred to when you're actually trying to refer to the imported csv module in the csv.render() call.